# specify moment at which to change value after converting (tri)annual-subject to month-subject observations (Stata)

Tags: stata

My goal is to convert a subject-triannual data set to one with subject-month observations, and specify the month at which one string variable (named "strvar" below) should change value, according to the var called "exact_time".

I have a data set with four records per subject (subject-year observations, aka multiple-record-per-subject data set), information was recorded every three years for each subject as follows:

[Table with tri-annual-subject obs. & exact_time var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riz8v.png)

"strvar" changes its value every three years. The variable "exact_time" records the exact (month.day.year) moment at which each the variable "strvar" changes its value. Once "strvar" varies, it keeps the same value for the following months, until the moment indicated by the next value of "exact_time"

I want Stata to change the value of "strvar" according to the variable "exact_time". For instance, subject 1 changed value of "strvar" in April 1, 1992, hence, I want Stata to assign the new value of "strvar" in April 1992. The value of "strvar" for subject 1 should remain the same until "exact_time" changes value (November.30.1995), hence, starting in November 1995, subject one should adopt the new value of "strvar". In 1998, "strvar" of subject one changed value once again, this time at the beginning of next year (January.1.1999), hence, "strvar" will adopt a new value starting in January.1999, until subject one's last observation (December 2002). As follows:

[table with monthly-subject obs, example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1i18.png)

I believe this can be achieved in in two steps, the second of which I need your support with:

1. Expand each tri-annual observation 36 times, so as to have monthly-subject observations, i.e., generate var "new_time". I guess this can be achieved through:
   expandcl 36, generate(new_time) cluster(subject)

   2. Instruct Stata to change the value "strvar" according to the date specified by "exact_time", which I have no idea how to do, and for which I would appreciate your support.

   Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will want to convert the exact_time variable to a Stata date variable, and you will want to be sure your new_time variable is also a Stata date variable. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 of the Stata User's Guide PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu (at least for Stata release 11 and later). I'm providing only comments rather than an answer because I cannot read the screenshot of your sample data into Stata to test whatever code I might think of.

Answer (score 1):

For future questions, please provide your failed attemps in form of code. They prove that you have done your part trying to solve the problem.
Also, please provide example data that can easily be copied/pasted by other users. Linking images is not the best option, for several reasons.

Find example code below.

```
clear 
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id str1 strvar str22 xtime
1 z "april 1, 1992"
1 u "november 30, 1995"
1 a "january 1, 1999"
2 b "january 15, 1989"
2 z "june 15, 1992"
2 c "august 30, 1995"
end

gen xtime2 = date(xtime, "MDY")
format %td xtime2

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

xtset id xtime2
tsfill 

gen strvar2 = strvar
replace strvar2 = strvar2[_n-1] if missing(strvar2)

browse
```

`tsfill` facilitates the job. Se also `help xtset`, `help subscripting` and `help datetime`.

Think about whether you actually need this. You are not adding any new information to the dataset, so what's the point of having a blown-up version of the original?

(The output doesn't exactly match the one in your image; but this *really* is meant to be an example.)